# Linq Detect Non Zero GUIDs in an array?

Tags: linq, guid

I am having a brain freeze. I have an array of n GUIDs and either all of them will have complete zeros, or they all won't. I am trying to come up with a succinct Linq query that will be true or false if they all contain "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" but can't, so here I am. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (arr.Any(g => g != Guid.Empty))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> guids = ...    
bool allZeros = guids.All(guid => guid == Guid.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
bool allZero = array.All(guid => guid == Guid.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking for Guid.Empty?  It is equal to a Guid with all zeroes.